# templateurl file in ui-bootstrap-tpls.js

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am working with angular ui-bootstrap.  Looking thorugh the ui-bootstrap-tpls.js file, i see this snippet

```
.directive('accordion', function () {
  return {
    restrict:'EA',
    controller:'AccordionController',
    transclude: true,
    replace: false,
    templateUrl: 'template/accordion/accordion.html'
  };
})
```

Notice: templateUrl: 'template/accordion/accordion.html'.

Where is this file?? It is nowhere to be found on my computer? I assume its calling it from remote location, if so, how do i get it local so i can work on it?  The greater question here is How to access ui-bootstrap built in directives so i can modify them to my liking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that file is coming from the $templateCache.  From Angular docs:

> > The first time a template is used, it is loaded in the template cache for quick retrieval. You can load templates directly into the
> >     cache in a script tag, or by consuming the $templateCache service
> >     directly.
>
> Adding via the script tag:
>
> This is the
>   content of the template
>
> Note: the script tag containing
>   the template does not need to be included in the head of the document,
>   but it must be a descendent of the $rootElement (IE, element with
>   ng-app attribute), otherwise the template will be ignored.

Here's an example:

```
angular.module('template/components/login.tpl.html', [])
    .run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache){
        $templateCache.put('template/components/login.tpl.html',
            '<div class="row">' +
                '<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-5 col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-2">' +
                    '<div>' +
                        '<label for="email">Email:</label>' +
                        '<input type="email" id="email" ng-model="user.username" class="required" name="email" autofocus />' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<div>' +
                        '<label for="pwd">Password:</label>' +
                        '<input type="password" id="pwd" class="required" ng-model="user.password" name="pwd"/>' +
                    '</div>' +
                    '<p>' +
                        '<button id="login" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="onSubmit(user)">Login</button>' +
                    '</p>' +
                '</div>' +
            '</div>');
    }]);
```

I would reference 'template/components/login.tpl.html' as my templateUrl